# Find all $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:$f(f(f(x)+y)+y)=x+y+f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:
$f(f(f(x)+y)+y)=x+y+f(y)$

I got the following:
(1)$f$ is injective
(2) $f(0)=0$

(3)$f(f(f(x)))=x$

But then how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you set $y=-f(x)$, then you get

$$f(f(0)-f(x))=x-f(x)+f(-f(x))$$

Now I'm not sure how you got $f(0)=0$, but if indeed you did, then we have

$$f(-f(x))=x-f(x)+f(-f(x))$$

which implies $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Denoting the functional equation by $P(x,y)$:
$$P(0,0)\implies f\Big(f\big(f(0)\big)\Big)=f(0)\tag0\label0$$
$$P\big(f(0),0\big),\eqref{0}\implies f\big(f(0)\big)=2f(0)\tag1\label1$$
$$\eqref{0},\eqref{1}\implies f\big(2f(0)\big)=f(0)\tag2\label2$$
$$P\big(0,f(0)\big),\eqref{1},\eqref{2}\implies f(0)=0$$